# How do I enforce a unidirectional one-to-many relationship?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-many

I have the following structure

```
 class User {

     String fname
     String lname
     String email

     static constraints = {
       fname(nullable:true, maxSize:30)
       fname(nullable:true, maxSize:30)
       email(nullable: true, email: true)
     }
}

class A extends User{
    String smtng
    List bInstance = new ArrayList()

    static hasMany = [b : B] 

    static constraints = {
       smtng(blank : true)
       b(nullable : true)
    }
}

class B {
    String smtng1
    String smtng2

    static constraints = {
       smtng1(blank:true, maxSize:50)
       smtng2(blank:true, maxSize:50)
    }
}
```

when I try to run this code it's displaying the following error

Full Stack trace........

```
    2014-09-03 12:37:11,010 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass.establishRelationshipForCollection(DefaultGrailsDomainClass.java:362)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass.establishRelationships(DefaultGrailsDomainClass.java:262)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass.<init>(DefaultGrailsDomainClass.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DomainClassArtefactHandler.newArtefactClass(DomainClassArtefactHandler.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.AnnotationDomainClassArtefactHandler.newArtefactClass(AnnotationDomainClassArtefactHandler.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:812)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:538)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.configureLoadedClasses(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.initialise(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:743)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.java:123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 23 more
2014-09-03 12:37:11,015 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass.establishRelationshipForCollection(DefaultGrailsDomainClass.java:362)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass.establishRelationships(DefaultGrailsDomainClass.java:262)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass.<init>(DefaultGrailsDomainClass.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DomainClassArtefactHandler.newArtefactClass(DomainClassArtefactHandler.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.AnnotationDomainClassArtefactHandler.newArtefactClass(AnnotationDomainClassArtefactHandler.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:812)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:538)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.configureLoadedClasses(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.initialise(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:743)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.java:123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-09-03 12:37:11,018 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    ... 5 more
2014-09-03 12:37:11,020 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    ... 5 more
2014-09-03 12:37:11,022 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-09-03 12:37:11,023 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    ... 5 more
2014-09-03 12:37:11,024 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    ... 5 more
2014-09-03 12:37:11,026 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-09-03 12:37:11,027 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [b] in class [class A] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [a] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [b:'myprop']
    ... 5 more
```

Notice:- I want unidirectional one-to-many relationship between class A and B
What do I have to do to create those unidirectional relationships? 
Thanks

Comment: `A` extends `User`. How does your `User` looks like?

Comment: i Updated the question...nothing special in user class though.

Comment: Please add the content of your constraints. I cannot reproduce your problem on a plain new Grails application.

Comment: You are aware that your code does not compile? Write `String` instead of `string` and write `static constraints` instead of `constraint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific example makes no sense, as `B` has *no* properties of type `A` that would be candidates for the back-reference, let alone two possible alternatives.  But in general, if you want to ensure that a `hasMany` relationship is unidirectional you can use a `mappedBy` value of `"none"`:

```
class A extends User{
    String smtng
    List b // note: do not include an initializer expression here

    static hasMany = [b : B]

    static mappedBy = [b:"none"]

    static constraints = {
       smtng(blank : true)
       b(nullable : true)
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry about the example. Its just a sample

Answer (score 0):

```
class A extends User{
   String smtng
   List bInstance

   static hasMany = [bInstance : B] 

   static constraints = {
      bInstance(nullable : true)
   }
}

class B {
  String smtng1
  String smtng2

  static belongsTo = [A]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do what the exception says:

```
class A extends user{
  static hasMany = [bInstance : B] 
  static mappedBy = [ B:'bref' ]
}
```

UPDATE

or define the back-ref explicitly:

```
class B {
  static belongsTo = [ a:A ]
}
```

Comment: `mappedBy` seems not mandatory for a unidirectional relationship. http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html

Comment: @abdul post the whole stacktrace

Comment: that makes it bidirectional.

Comment: technically speaking, it's unidirectional, but in the opposite way, as you are referencing per FK the A table from B table,